# Создание таймера до момента во времени

Tags: javascript

Помогите создать таймер, вот с таким дизайном:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кода на JavaScript нету, поскольку, я не знаю этого языка. Проект большой, могу только скрин выложить. Не хватает только этого таймера.

```js
function startTimer() {
  var my_timer = document.getElementById("my_timer");
  var time = my_timer.innerHTML;
  var arr = time.split(":");
  var h = arr[0];
  var m = arr[1];
  var s = arr[2];
  if (s == 0) {
    if (m == 0) {
      if (h == 0) {
        alert("Время вышло");
        window.location.reload();
        return;
      }
      h--;
      m = 60;
      if (h < 10) h = "0" + h;
    }
    m--;
    if (m < 10) m = "0" + m;
    s = 59;
  } else s--;
  if (s < 10) s = "0" + s;
  document.getElementById("my_timer").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
  setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}
```

```html
<p><span id="my_timer" style="color: #f00; font-size: 150%; font-weight: bold;">15:48:27</span></p>
```

Comment: Круто, что перезалил, но нам нужен код твоей реализации или попытки.

Comment: объясните по пунктам что он делает, если суть это можете?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В принципе можно так:

```js
function timer() {
  time_rest = ((time_rest < 0) ? 0: time_rest - 1);

  var hours = Math.floor(time_rest / 3600);
  var minutes = Math.floor((time_rest - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
  var seconds =  Math.floor((time_rest - ((hours * 3600) + (minutes * 60))));

  if(hours <  10) {
    hours = "0" + hours;
  }

  if(minutes <  10) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }

  if(seconds <  10) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName("hours")[0].innerHTML = hours;
  document.getElementsByClassName("minutes")[0].innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementsByClassName("seconds")[0].innerHTML = seconds;

  if(time_rest == 0) {
    //location.reload(); // обновляем страницу, если время вышло (скрыл для теста)
  }
}

var time_now = new Date().getTime() / 1000; // текущее время в формате timestamp
var time_to = new Date("21 June 2016 22:33:44").getTime() / 1000; // финальное время в формате timestamp

var time_rest = Math.floor(time_to - time_now); // сколько осталось секунд до финального времени в формату timestamp

// делим на 1000, т.к. ответит приходит в миллисекундах 

timer();

setInterval(function() {
  timer();
}, 1000);
```

```css
  .timer {
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #98001A;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  
  .timer .title {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #000;
  }

  .timer .hours, .timer .minutes, .timer .seconds {
    display: inline;
    padding: 1.6px;
  }

  .timer .colon {
    display: inline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="timer">
  <div class="title">До конца акции осталось:</div>


  <div class="hours">00</div>

  <div class="colon">:</div>  

  <div class="minutes">00</div>

  <div class="colon">:</div>  

  <div class="seconds">00</div>
</div>
```

Comment: про подписи забыли: часы, минуты, секунды, а вообще +1

Comment: @dDevil благодарю) так сказали вроде бы без подписей, или я не так понял: 
 `только этого таймера.

15:48:27`

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: @TigoPapoyan не за что)

Comment: `0-1 : 37 : 26` :)

Comment: В вашем таймере ошибка, исправьте, пожалуйста, код

Comment: можете поменять `time_to`, я просто ставил +сутки, так как нужно было тестировать в часах, а не днях

Comment: @VenZell это не ошибка, время уже просто прошло

Comment: @ikerya, это ошибка. Если время прошло, оно не должно идти в минус. Должно быть `00:00:00`.

Comment: хорошо, сейчас будет. а вообще после истечения времени обновляется страница

Comment: @VenZell сделал